# Why this onChange function works?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am now confused about the onChange event handler. I just want to knows how it works.
Traditionally if we want to keep track of value inside the input box or text area we pass a variable to the function.

```
<InputDialogContent
  inputLabel="Email Address"
  inputType="email"
  onChange={(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): any =>
    onInputChange(ev.target.value)
  }
/>
```

In this case we are passing in `ev.target.value`

and the function is

```
function onInputChange(input: any) {
  if (isValidEmail(input)) {
    setEnableLoginButton(true);
  } else {
    setEnableLoginButton(false);
  }
}
```

it works fine. I know that The `ev.target.value` become `input`
But one of my senior change the code into something like this and is still working.
I am wondering why its is working when it doesn't pass a variable like the above function

```
<InputDialogContent
  inputLabel="Email Address"
  inputType="email"
  onChange={onInputChange}
/>
```

the function  become like this. From what i see the function still expecting an variable to be passed into but there is no variable being passed. && THIS FUNCTION STILL WORKS. **WHY ?**

```
function onInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
  setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(e.target.value));
}

const isValidEmail = (email: string): boolean => {
  const validateFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (email.match(validateFormat)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

I am using typescript and its a function component.

Comment: Reference - https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is an inline-defined function, the other is a function passed by reference.

Your `InputDialogContent` component expects a `onChange` prop with the signature `(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): any`.

In your first example you are passing an inline-defined function with that signature:

```
(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): any =>
  onInputChange(ev.target.value)
}
```

In your second example you are passing the `onInputChange` function directly. `onInputChange` has the same signature as required by the `onChange` prop (that's how you're calling it, a function with a single parameter of type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>`).

The reason both do the same is that your inline-defined function simply calls `onInputChange` inside passing it the same parameter, so in essence doing *nothing*.

You are doing this:

```
function addNothingToX(x) {
  return x;
}

function addTenToX(x) {
  return x + 10;
}

// all these three are equivalent
console.log(addTenToX(0));
console.log(addNothingToX(addTenToX(0));
console.log(((x) => x)(addTenToX(0)); // this is what you are basically doing
```

You could do this too:

```
<InputDialogContent
  onChange={e => setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(e.target.value))}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Function 1

```
(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): any => onInputChange(ev.target.value)
```

has type `(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void`

#### Function 2

```
function onInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
  setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(e.target.value));
}
```

has type `(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void`

Both functions have the same signature (that means you call both functions in the same way), so if the first function is assignable to `onChange`, then the second function is assignable as well.

From 1 to 2 there are only a couple of simplifications. The first function only gets the event value and passes it down to `onInputChange`. This can be merged into one function, which happens in example 2.